# UIModalTransitionStyle.FlipHorizontal doesn't flip

Tags: ios, swift

I am new in Cocoa and Swift, and I'm trying to use the `UIModalTransitionStyle.FlipHorizontal` transition to switch from `ViewController1` to `ViewContoller2` and vice-verse.

Unfortunately the switch from controller 1 to controller 2 **occurs without any transition**, but works correctly on dismiss.

I use this code in `ViewController1`:

```
let ctrl = ViewController2(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
ctrl.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.FlipHorizontal
self.presentViewController(ctrl, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

and this code in `ViewControler2`:

```
self.presentingViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Where are you calling `self.presentViewController(ctrl, animated: true, completion: nil)`? If its in `viewDidLoad`, it needs to be in `viewDidAppear` for you to see it

Comment: This is broken for me as well, worked fine in ios7. Not sure if something has changed in the API or something is wrong in the beta